# Sequelize - Where clause in a nested 'include' statement does return results correctly in Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 5 db tables:

`Template`, `Capability`, `Deployment`, `Level`, `Requirement`

```
Template (PK) -> has many Capability (FK)

Capability (PK) -> has many Deployments (FK) && Capability has many Levels (FK)

Level (PK) -> has many Requirement (FK)
```

I want to retrieve all templates, with the related foreign keys all the way down to the Requirements.
However, I would like to limit the number of Levels to just the ones that are not deleted (`isDeleted : false`).

This works if there is DATA retrieved, BUT if there are no records returned from the Levels tables based on the Where (isDeleted), Sequelize will return an empty array for the Deployments table as well.  This query correct data if records are found from the Levels table.  However, shouldn't the records from the deployment table be returned regardless since it is a different table?

```
Template.hasMany(Capability, { foreignKey : {name : 'templateId'} })
Capability.hasMany(Deployment, { foreignKey : {name : 'capabilityId'} });
Capability.hasMany(Level,  {foreignKey : {name : 'capabilityId'} });
Level.hasMany(Requirement,  {foreignKey : {name : 'levelId'}});

const allModules = 
    await Template.findAll({            
        include : [ {
            model: Capability, 
            as: 'capabilities',
            include : [ 
                {
                model: Deployment,
                as : 'deployments'
            },{
                model: Level,
                as : 'levels', 
                where : { isDeleted : false }, // this is the failing part ( if no records are returned both the Deployment recordset and the Level recordset fail)
                include : [{
                    model : Requirement,
                    as : 'requirements',
                }],
            },]
        }],
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be asking for something impossible.  You said:

```
Capability.hasMany(Level, ...
Level.hasMany(Requirement ....
```

If there is no Level (or, if the level is marked as deleted), the link between Capability and Requirement is broken, so those Requirements cannot be retrieved.  Under what capability would they appear?

OTOH, If you're looking for other outer join situations, try `required : false`.  For example, you could add this to your query to retrieve Capabilities that have no deployments as follows:

```
   ...    
   include : [ {
            model: Capability, 
            as: 'capabilities',
            include : [ 
                {
                model: Deployment,
                as : 'deployments',
                required : false            // outer join
            }
    ...
```